# php email from html form

Tags: php, html

So I've had some issues trying to get my php code to work. I found a form php handler which I want to send the email on the back end for the users.

```
 <?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    ob_start();
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];//Sender first name//
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];//sender last name//
    $subject = "Contact Request.";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $to = "-myemail@outlook.com-"; // this is your Email address

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

    header('Location: http://-mysite-/thankyou.html');
    exit();
}
?>
```

Here is the HTML form info:

```
<form action="php/email.php" method="post" name = "email form" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="container" align="center">
    <label for="firstname"></label>
    <strong>*</strong><input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="first_name" required>
    <br>
    <label for="lastname"></label>
    <strong>*</strong><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="last_name" required>
    <br>
    <label for="email"></label>
    <strong>*</strong><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
    <br>
    <label for="phoneno"></label>
    <input type="phoneno" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" name="phone_number">
    <br>
    <label for="interested"></label>
    <t> Brief description of project:</t><br>
    <textarea style="width:100% height:60%" align="center" name="message">
    </textarea><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn" value="Send Form"><strong>Submit</strong></button>
  </form>
```

I can't figure out why the page on submit does redirect to the email.php but doesn't do anything from there. Do I need to contact the site support team to restart my php services? I've been smacking my head against the keyboard for the last 2 days as to why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't field in your form with `name="submit"` and trying to get its value in PHP: `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`.

Bonus tip: don't use name `submit` for any field of the form, cause some browsers getting fooled with this. Instead use `formsubmit`, `submitted` or anything else.

just add this field in your form

```html
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
```

andchange condition in PHP to

```php
if(isset($_POST['submitted']) && intval($_POST['submitted']) == 1)...
```

Comment: I've added those and still results in submit page just as blank white page. Its not redirecting like the end is meant to do.

Comment: Debug it step by step, during sending what data are sent via browser inspector. In PHP script what arrives by `var_dump($_POST)`. We can't do it for you